# CSS media query issue displaying menu on Safari

Tags: css, responsive

To get a faster website, I am migrating my WordPress from the Astra Theme with Elementor to the Kadence Theme with Gutemberg.  I am hoping to get some SEO success as I add content.

The new version is on [Http://staging2.DearReal.com](https://staging2.dearreal.com)
username pawpatrol
password ninjagolego

I am having issues with the header menu desktop version.  The bellow CSS, formating the fonts in the menu, is not considered in Safari, and I sometimes get the strange behaviour in Chrome.

The second, less important, issue is with "make clicking outside the menu close it".  I have hacked this by adding 1000 px right and left of the area, but it would be better to stretch the area to the end of the screen dynamically.

Many thanks for your time.
Regards,
Henri

```css
/* primary menu links */
#primary-menu li {
  flex-grow: 1;
}


/* desktop */
@media only screen and (min-width: 842px) {
  .mainmenu-link-css a,
  .mainmenu-link-css a:visited {
    color: #2D3748;
    display: block;
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .mainmenu-link-css a:active,
  .mainmenu-link-css a:hover {
    color: #A74646;
    display: block;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  /* taken out stuff that should not be relevant */
}


/* mobile */
/* formating mobile menu */
@media only screen and (max-width: 842px) {
  .mainmenu-link-css a,
  .mainmenu-link-css a:active,
  .mainmenu-link-css a:visited {
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) !important;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 22px !important;
  }
  .popup-drawer .drawer-overlay,
  .popup-drawer-layout-fullwidth .drawer-inner {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0) !important;
  }
  .menu-toggle-close {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) !important;
  }
  .toggle-close-bar {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) !important;
  }
  .popup-drawer .drawer-header {
    min-height: 80px;
  }
  /* make clicking outsite the menu close it */
  button.menu-toggle-close:after {
    position: relative;
  }
  button.menu-toggle-close:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -0px;
    bottom: -1000px;
    left: -1000px;
    right: -10px;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .drawer-menu-container {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 3;
  }
  /* taken out stuff that should not be relevant */
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please add more details like html in a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) at best in a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for checking this out.  This was solved by adding an !important to

color: #2D3748 !important;

All issues are due to conflicts between the WordPress Theme CSS and my CSS.  Was not able to replicate this in StackOverflow.

My recommendation to anyone getting similar issues is to invest in a child theme or even better your own theme.  Don't believe the hype with Themes and plugins they are taking you for a ride, a maze of over-bloated code and conflicts.  Invest in learning CSS, WordPress and tailor your code for the best output and performance.  I am on this journey to sanity.